# Spinner and Toolbar

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar

How with `Spinner` to implement such a drop down menu? (An item should not touch the Toolbar). I looked through lots of examples, a drop-down list touches `Toolbar`.

Or is it better to implement it another way?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Like you want the toolbar to expand and show a LinearLayout/ListView?

Comment: @RamithDR I want to make a filter for RecyclerViewstyle, as in the screenshot.
Drop-down menu should be imposed on RecyclerView